# Passing an interface to a base class - C#

Tags: c#, oop

If I have the following code:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    public void SendName(<Take in an interface>)
    { // Do stuff }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass, IMyProperties
{
   public string IMyProperties.Name { get; set; }

   public void Derived()
   {
       IProperties.Name = "Dave";
   }

   public void SendNameToBase
   {
     base.SendName(//I want to send IProperties);
   }
}
```

How do I send `IProperties` to the base class?

Comment: What do you mean by "send `IProperties`"? Your code doesn't really make sense, and you haven't given us any sense of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by `public void SendName(<Take in an interface>)`? Do you want to pass a type? A string name? A particular instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your base class's method should be defined like such:

```
public void SendName(IProperties props) 
{ // Do stuff }
```

You call this method from the child class like this: (assuming you want to pass the current instance of the your child class, since it implements `IProperties`)

```
base.SendName(this);
```

Note:  I'm also assuming that `IMyProperties` == `IProperties` in your code example.

Comment: Except that `interface` is a keyword :-)

Comment: Good Catch.  You know what I meant.  :P

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion in explaining what I was trying to do. If the class implemented multiple interfaces, the "this" can be used to refer to either of them?

Comment: Yep.  Passing `this` means you are passing an instance to the current instance of the class.  Following polymorphism, you can pass an instance of a class as any type or interface it inherits from (also know as "boxing").

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by sending an interface?

If you want to pass the type statically, you can use a [generic (i.e. templated) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
public void SendName<T>(T properties)
    where T : IProperties    // types passed in must derive from IProperties
{
    var name = properties.Name;
    // ...
}

//...

// Usage:
base.SendName<IProperties>(this);
```

If you want to send the type at runtime, you can pass around [Type objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

```
public void SendName(Type type)
{ /* Do stuff */ }

//...

// Usage:
base.SendName(typeof(IProperties));
```

Answer (score 1):

well since you explicitly setup the interface, you would have to do

```
base.SendName((IMyProperties)this);
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. The `Derived` class *is* an *IMyProperties*, so the cast is not needed. The code in the `SendName` method will succeed calling `Name` because it doesn't know it received a `Derived`. It knows just that it got an `IMyProperties`. Such casts *would* be necessary only when you have a `Derived` reference and try to call `Name`. Then you'd have to first cast to `IMyProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe if you declared the variable in the base clase you would be able to access IProperties in both functions

```
public abstract BaseClass 
{
   public string IMyProperties.Name { get; set; }
   public void SendName(<Take in an interface>) 
   { // Do stuff } 
}
```